# How can I have my web server automatically rebuild the files it serves?

Tags: apache, webserver, build-automation

I sometimes write client-side-only web applications, and I like a simple and fast development cycle. This leads me to project layouts which explicitly have no build step, so that I can just edit source files and then reload in the web browser. This is not always a healthy constraint to place on the design. I would therefore like the following functionality to use in my *development* environment:

**Whenever the server receives a `GET /foo/bar` request and translates it to a file `/whatever/foo/bar`, it executes `cd /whatever && make foo/bar` before reading the file.**

What is the **simplest** way to accomplish this?

The best form of solution would be an Apache configuration, preferably one entirely within `.htaccess` files; failing that, a lightweight web server which has such functionality already; or one which can be programmed to do so.

---

Since I have attracted quite a lot of “don't do that” responses, let me reassure you on a few points:

- This is client-side-only development — the files being served are all that matters, and the build will likely be very lightweight (e.g. copying a group of files into a target directory layout, or packing some .js files into a single file). Furthermore, the files will typically be loaded once per edit-and-reload cycle — so interactive response time is not a priority.
- Assume that the build system is fully aware of the relevant dependencies — if nothing has changed, no rebuilding will happen.
- If it turns out to be impractically slow despite the above, I'll certainly abandon this idea and find other ways to improve my workflow — but I'd like to at least give it a try.

Comment: You want to rebuild your application upon every request to the server?

Comment: Why do you need to create a file before it's been accessed? The way you are thinking is completely wrong! You can route "not found" requests to default page. Or if all of that is about of build, use tools like Apache Ant, Jenkins and others...

Comment: @MikeBrant I'm assuming a sufficiently refined build system which rebuilds only changed files — certainly not from scratch. And this is a client-heavy or all-client application running in development mode — the request rate is very low.

Comment: @RomanNewaza The file probably already exists — what I want is for it to be *up-to-date* vs. its source files.

Comment: @KevinReid: I suggest you to google about deployment.

Answer (score 1):

You could use http://aspen.io/.

Presuming the makefile does some magic, you could make a simplate that does:

```
import subprocess
RESULTFILE = "/whatever/foo/bar"
^L
subprocess.call(['make'])
response.body = ''.join(open(resultfile).readlines())
^L
```

but if it's less magic, you could of course encode the build process into the simplate itself (using something like https://code.google.com/p/fabricate/ ) and get rid of the makefile entirely.

Comment: This woodenly follows the OP's reqs, but Aspen is no-build to start with. Why not just do:

^L
^L
Greetings, program!

(Blech, bad formatting here in comments. Wanna update your answer, pjz? :-) )

Comment: I presumed that 'make' does a bunch of catenation and minification and other magic stuff.  But yeah, if it's a simple file then sure.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm a lazy sod, I'd suggest something like that:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(.*)(/|)$ /make.php?base=$1&make=$2 [L,NC]
```

A regex pattern like that provides the two required parameters -

Which then can be passed to a shell-script by PHP function exec():

You might need to add exclusions above the pattern or inclusions to the pattern,
e.g define the first back-reference by words - else it would match other requests as well (which shouldn't be re-written).

The parameters can be accessed in shell-script like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/$1
make $2
```

Answer (score -1):

This seems like a really bad idea. You will add a HUGE amount of latency to each request waiting for the "make" to finish. In a development environment that is okay, but in production you are going to kill performance.

That said, you could write a simple apache module that would handle this:
http://linuxdocs.org/HOWTOs/Apache-Overview-HOWTO-12.html

I would still recommend considering if this is what you want to do. In development you know if you change a file that you need to remake. In production it is a performance killer.

Comment: This is for development only — I've added that explicitly to the question now. I'm a bit puzzled as to how I gave the impression I'd be using this in production — could you clarify?

Comment: Your post was obviously unclear since I am not the only one that misunderstood it.

Comment: Writing a module is certain overkill according to the requirements.